# setScrollX function doesn't work well

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have some source code for scrolling.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.txtv);
    HorizontalScrollView sv = findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    sv.setScrollX(100);
}
```

I want to set x scroll position to 100px.
But `setScrollX` function doesn't work well.
What's the problem? How should I do?

Comment: setScrollX() is taking pixels I believe and not dp. What output you are getting currently?

Comment: Thanks for your replying.  Currently,  x scroll position never move.

Comment: You want to scroll vertically or Horizontally? to scroll vertically use setScrollY() and for horizontally setScrollX()

Comment: Of course,  I want to scroll horizontally. That's why I am gonna use setScrollX function.   But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that at that point the actual view is not laid out yet. You have to delay the scrolling until `HorizontalScrollView` is laid out:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        HorizontalScrollView sv = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        sv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sv.smoothScrollBy(100, 0);
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All You have to do is

```
         sv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 sv.smoothScrollBy(100, 0);// x,y
            }
        });
```